# android java: accessing class that has parentActivity

Tags: java, android, class, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have GPS listener class `AppLocationListener` that has a parent activity `GPSSensorActivity` (not shown below).

I'm trying to access `AppLocationListener` from another class `QuestionSearch` by using `AppLocationListener searchLL = new AppLocationListener(); searchLL.parentActivity = this;` but using `this` gives a type mismatch between `QuestionSearch` and `GPSSensorActivity`. .

Is this because it's not possible to access classes that have parent activities? How can I access `AppLocationListener`. `QuestionSearch` is something I've added on to existing code that isn't my original code, I'm trying to  I am new to java and don't fully understand passing data and linking classes/methods yet.

```
// AppLocationListener class
import java.util.ArrayList;
...

public class AppLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public GPSSensorActivity parentActivity;

    public ArrayList<GeoPoint> pointList;

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {            
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {

    }

} 

// QuestionSearch class
import java.util.ArrayList;
...

public class QuestionSearch extends Activity {

 private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 1; // in Meters
 private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE = 5000; // in Milliseconds
 private LocationManager locationManager;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_quizmap);

     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     AppLocationListener searchLL = new AppLocationListener();
     searchLL.parentActivity = this;

     ArrayList<GeoPoint> pointList = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
     ...
        // add these points to the list
        pointList.add(gMapPoint);
        pointList.add(gMapPoint2);
     pointList.add(gMapPoint3);


        // now set up the location manager and listener
     searchLL.pointList = pointList;
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                     LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                     MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE, 
                     MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                     searchLL
     ); 
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to pass `this` in `searchLL.parentActivity = this;` your `QuestionSearch` should be `GPSSensorActivity` or should extend it.

> Is this because it's not possible to access classes that have parent activities?

No, it has nothing to do with it, it's a pure Java matter - just pass right classes where they are expected.

Comment: thanks. Coming from an R background to java's a bit sticky. Got to rethink in terms of OOP.

Comment: @mark you're welcome. Just tell me if you'll need a further help.

Comment: appreciated, I certainly will